# onClick, onLongClick and swipe at the same time

Tags: android, onclick, swipe, gesture

I'm working on application that has a list view, and on each cell of this list I'm having:

- onClick that takes me to another screen.
- onLongClick that displays a dialog.
- swipe from right to left that shows two buttons.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to swipe, I also got the dialog opened at the same time. (onLongClick and Swipe activated at the same time)

So here is my code :

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 200;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        }
                    }
                    Log.e("diffX", String.valueOf(diffX));
                    Log.e("velocityX", String.valueOf(velocityX));
                    result = true;
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
                result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Code for the on Click, LongClick:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
           view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("LongClick", "Long click");


                  // code for the dialog
                }
            });

           view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(MainActivity.this) {
                public void onSwipeTop() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "top", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onSwipeRight() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onSwipeLeft() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                public void onSwipeBottom() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "bottom", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });

        }
```

Comment: set the result to `false` when you swipe left / right etc

Comment: @blundell did not work.

Comment: I have a same issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/09/15/crossing-things-off-lists-in-android-09-sdk/) you can find an excellent tutorial solving your problem.

Essentially, you will create a transparent view in front of the ListView which consumes horizontal motion events and passes non-horizontal motion events back down to the ListView.

Answer (score 2):

Why did you set `OnLongClickListener` separately ?!?
Override `onLongPress(MotionEvent e)` method of `GestureListener`  in the `OnSwipeTouchListener` class, It should work.